# EC2 launch configuration user data is not executed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, launch-configuration

I've just created a new Launch Configuration to use with an Auto Scaling group. When a new EC2 instance is launched, I would like the script to be executed.

In details:

- I have a script `deploy.sh` that updates my application code using git...
- When a new instance is launched by Auto Scaling, it should execute the script that I've provided via User Data in the Launch Configuration (attached on autoscaling group).

My user data is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/ec2-user/deploy.sh
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Have you looked at your instance's system log? See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html

Answer (score 5):

Can you check the permission of your deploy script?

You can login to the instance and check the logs of User Data execution. Logs are at `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Answer (score 0):

I've checked `cloud-init-output.log` and seems everything is okay.
I've done another test now and the new instance has the right code.
Probably there was a syntax error in launch configuration user data.

So, the right user data is

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/ec2-user/deploy.sh
```

Now I should add `yum update` before my custom script.